# Prove that $\int \limits_0^{2a}f(x)dx=\int_0^a[f(x)+f(2a-x)]dx$

Tags: calculus, integration

How do I attempt this? What is the aim of the proof?

I've been trying silly things with the LHS and the RHS but cannot produce anything of use.

Can someone offer a very slight hint on proceeding?

Thanks

I did this so far:

$\displaystyle \int \limits_0^{2a}f(x)dx=\int \limits_0^a[f(x)+f(2a-x)]dx = \int \limits_0^a f(x)dx + \int \limits_0^a f(2a-x)dx$

Comment: $$\int_a^{2a} f(x)\,dx = \int_0^a f(2a-x)\,dx$$

Answer (score 2):

Essentially,
this formula splits $[0, 2a]$
into $[0, a]$ and $[a, 2a]$
and then fiddles with the
integral over the second interval.

More explicitly,

$\begin{align}
\int_0^{2a} f(x) dx
&= \int_0^{a} f(x) dx+\int_a^{2a} f(x) dx\\
&= \int_0^{a} f(x) dx+\int_0^{a} f(x+a) dx\\
&= \int_0^{a} f(x) dx-\int_a^{0} f((a-x)+a) dx 
\quad \text{ (replace } x \text{ by }a-x)\\
&= \int_0^{a} f(x) dx-\int_a^{0} f(2a-x) dx\\
&= \int_0^{a} f(x) dx+\int_0^a f(2a-x) dx
\quad \text{ (reverse direction of integration)}\\
&= \int_0^{a} (f(x) dx+f(2a-x)) dx\\
\end{align}
$

Note that this also proves that
$$\int_0^{2a} f(x) dx
= \int_0^{a} (f(x) + f(x+a)) dx
$$

Comment: In the first line, why is the 2nd integral $\displaystyle \int_a^{2a} f(x)dx$ and not $\displaystyle\int_0^a f(x)dx$?

Comment: Because the integral from 0 to 2a is split into 0 to a and a to 2a.

Answer (score 1):

$$\int_0^a f(2a-x)dx = \int_a^{2a} f(y)dy.$$

Comment: how do I show this? I tried letting $u = 2a-x$ so $du = -dx$. When $x=0, u=2a, when x = a, u = a$. So then I have $\displaystyle -\int_{2a}^a f(u)du$

Comment: $-\int_{2a}^{a}f(u)du=-(-\int_{a}^{2a}f(u)du)$